# Using enum item to call a method

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum with 30 items in it. Each item has a corresponding function with the same name. I would like to be able to call the function by referencing the enum at a certain position.

So if the value at `enum[0] = Foo`, I would like to be able to call `Foo(string bar)` by using something like `enum(0)("foobar")`

In the end the point is I am running each function as a task like so:

```
enum Test { AA, BB, CC, DD ....}
tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => { prices[0] = AA("a string"); });
tasks[1] = Task.Run(() => { prices[1] = BB("a string"); });
tasks[2] = Task.Run(() => { prices[2] = CC("a string"); });
//for 30 tasks
```

What I would like to do is something along the lines of:

```
enum Test { AA, BB, CC, DD ....}
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => { prices[i] = (Test)i("a string"); });
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Is this something that is even possible?

EDIT:

The enum relates to controls on a form so i have an array of textboxs, label and a array of prices that is populated with the results of the functions:

```
enum Dealers { Dealer1, Dealer2 ... Dealer29, Dealer30 };

static int noOfDealers = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Dealers)).Length;
decimal[] prices = new decimal[noOfDealers];
TextBox[] textBox = new TextBox[noOfDealers];
Label[] boxes = new Label[noOfDealers];

for (int i = 0; i < noOfDealers; i++)
{
    textBox[i] = Controls.Find("txt" + (Dealers)i, true)[0] as TextBox;
    boxes[i] = Controls.Find("box" + (Dealers)i, true)[0] as Label;
    prices[i] = 0;
}

//RUN 30 TASKS TO POPULATE THE PRICES ARRAY

for (int i = 0; i < noOfDealers; i++)
{
   textBox[i].Text = "£" + prices[i].ToString();
}
```

```
//LOOP THROUGH PRICES ARRAY AND FIND CHEAPEST PRICE, THEN COLOUR THE LABEL BACKGROUND GREEN FOR THE TEXT BOX WITH THE NAME AT ENUM VALUE WHATEVER I IS
```

I guess i am just trying to make my code as concise as possible, there is the potential for the amount of tasks to double and didn't want to end up with 60 lines to populate the tasks array

Comment: You could do that via reflection, but are you *really* sure storing function names in an enum is a good choice?

Comment: You would have to use reflection to find the `MethodInfo` based on the name of the method based on the name of the enumeration value. You could then call it using reflection. You could wrap this up in a method and call it by passing in the enum and the parameter. Note that the parameters should not differ between methods.

Comment: Noooooo! Hopefully it's not possible. This sounds like an XY issue to me. What are you really trying to achieve? At the moment you guess that an enum and methods named like the enum are the solution. But there might be an even cleaner approch if we just knew what you really want to do.

Comment: Alternatively you could create a `Dictionary<Test,Func<string,decimal>>` lookup and use that. I made the assumption that it takes a string parameter and returns a decimal.

Comment: @Igor: don't do it. In 3 years, this guy will not understand his own source code any more.

Comment: @ThomasWeller ive added some of the code to try and clear it up abit

Comment: Is there a reason you using TextBoxes and Labels instead of `DataGridView`? Is this `Winforms`?

Comment: Yes winforms, the labels act as borders to each element (consisting of a picturebox and a textbox) so i can set the background colour of the label, its to make the UI look nicer. But thats irrelevant to the question really...

Answer (score 8):

I would create dictionary and map enum to actions:

```
  Dictionary<Test, Func<string,double>> actions = new Dictionary<Test, Func<string,double>>()
            {
                {Test.AA, (x) => { return 5;}},
                {Test.BB, (x) => { return 15; }},
            }; //x is your string

            var res = actions[Test.AA]("hello");
```

Comment: The code is expecting an output, probably a decimal. Instead of `Action<string>`, `Func<string,decimal>` might be a better choice.

Comment: @Igor it's just an example, it's up to OP what he wants to achieve. But agreed that answering the question there should be a return type, I'll edit

Comment: and maybe use an `int` as key? it seems that the only value of the enum was to index the functions

Comment: @KMoussa the enum also relates to TextBoxes and Labels on a form, and the position of the enum relates to the position of a prices array

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest using a built in construct - like an extension method and a simple switch:

```
public static int GetPriceWithString(this Test test, string str)
{
    switch (test)
    {
         case Test.AA:
             break;
         case Test.BB:
             break;
         case Test.CC:
             break;
         case Test.DD:
             break;
         default:
             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(test), test, null);
     }
}
```

then your loop looks almost the same:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => 
              { 
                   prices[i] = ((Test)i).GetPriceWithString("a string"); 
              });
}
```

What you want to do is possible with reflection, which can be a powerful tool - but ideally should only be used as a last resort, as it will hide what could be compile time errors, and cause less code readability.

Using a simple switch like this makes your code self-documented, so when you come back to this in a month you can quickly remember what the intention was.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an array of delegates:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int AA(string a) { return 0; }
        private static int BB(string a) { return 1; }
        private static int CC(string a) { return 2; }

        private static Func<string, int>[] functions = new Func<string, int>[] { AA, BB, CC };
        private static int[] prices = new int[functions.Length];
        private static Task[] tasks = new Task[functions.Length];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < functions.Length; ++i)
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => { prices[i] = functions[i]("a string"); });
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An eg. speaks a lot more than words.

I used it in a winform so the `this` refers to win form.
I have assumed all your methods are public , have same signature & return the same type.

```
    enum MyName { AA,BB,CC};

//Call this in one of your methods

    string [] strVal= Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyName));
                int x = CallFunction(strVal[0], "A");
                int y = CallFunction(strVal[1], "h");
                int z = CallFunction(strVal[1], "C");

//End Call this in one of your methods


     int CallFunction(string strName,string strValue)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(this.GetType().InvokeMember(strName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod|BindingFlags.Instance, null, this, new object[] { strValue }));
            }

     public int AA(string s)
            {
                return 1;
            }

           public int BB(string s)
            {
                return 2;
            }

           public int CC(string s)
            {
                return 3;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. I hope somebody will consider it as overkill :)

Create abstract class DealerBase.

```
public abstract class DealerBase
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    protected DealerBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }  

    public abstract void UpdatePrice();   
}
```

Then create classes for every dealers you have and implement own logic for `UpdatePrice` method.

```
public class Dealer1 : DealerBase
{
    public Dealer1() : base("DealerOne") { }

    public override void UpdatePrice()
    {
        //Calculate price
        Price = DealerOneCalculationMethod();
    } 
}

public class Dealer2 : DealerBase
{
    public Dealer2() : base("DealerTwo") { }

    public override void UpdatePrice()
    {
        //Calculate price
        Price = DealerTwoCalculationMethod();
    } 
}
```

And so on..

Then you just create collection of dealers which can be easily iterated

```
var dealers = new List<DealerBase>
{
    new Dealer1(),
    new Dealer2()
}

foreach(var dealer in dealers)
{
    dealer.UpdatePrice();
}
```

You can loop dealers and generate textboxes, labels in the winforms.

But I suggest to use `DataGridView` where code will be tiny clearer.
First implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the base class `DealerBase`

```
public abstract class DealerBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; }

    protected decimal _Price;
    public decimal Price 
    { 
        get { return _Price; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_Price, value)) return;
            _Price = value;
            // next method will inform DataGridView about changes
            // and update value there too 
            RaisePropertyChanged();         
        }

    protected DealerBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }  

    public abstract void UpdatePrice();  

    // Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  
}
```

The in the Form you can create `BindingList<DealerViewModelBase>` and set it to `DataGridView.DataSource`

```
public class YourForm: Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dealers = new List<DealerBase>
        {
            new Dealer1(),
            new Dealer2()
        };

        var bindSource = new BindingList<DealerBase>(dealers);
        dataGridView.DataSource = bindSource;
    }

    // Add button which update prices for all dealers
    private void ButtonUpdatePrices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dealers = (BindingList<DealerBase>)dataGridView.DataSource;
        foreach (var dealer in dealers)
        {
            dealer.UpdatePrice();
            // Because we call `RaisePropertyChanged` in
            // setter of Price - prices will be automatically
            // updated in DataGridView
        }
    }       
}
```

Idea of this approach you put different logic of different dealers in the separated class which. Because all dealer classes will inherit from same abstract class you can add different dealers to the collection.

You already have hardcoded enums and correspondent method which you try to link together. This approach make using of dealers collection little bid easy